Rendering GIF in Kdenlive results in pixel dithering/discoloration
Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
If I render a video in Kdenlive as an MP4 file, it looks fine. If I render it as a GIF, the solid grey part of the video has this odd pixel discoloration effect? I don't know how to describe it, grey image broken up by green and red pixel pattern. So here's an image:

I've tried enabling "Render full color range," "Render at Preview Resolution," neither of them seem to fix it.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

Important note: GIF has a maximum of 256 colors (8 bit info) for the frame, you're seeing effects of that limitation. e.g. Floyd-Steinberg dithering will lessen the "artifacts", but create a grainy appearance. more info -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF

Important note: GIF has a maximum of 256 colors (8 bit info) for the frame [block], you're seeing effects of that limitation. e.g. Floyd-Steinberg dithering will lessen the "artifacts", but create a grainy appearance. more info -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF - this is nothing Ubuntu specific.

Check out this comment/post: ffmpeg-high-quality-animated-gif

Converting from MP4 to GIF using gifski fixed the pixel dithering. Thank you JayCravens for your comment!
